# What is this S.android.intent.extra.TEXT in the application schema

Tags: javascript, android, url-scheme

can anyone help me understand this `S.android.intent.extra.TEXT` What is this `S.android.intent.extra.TEXT` where are they?

`intent:#Intent;action=android.intent.action.SEND;type=text/plain;S.android.intent.extra.TEXT={Share%20Text};S.android.intent.extra.SUBJECT=Amazing;S.browser_fallback_url=;end`

I spent hours and still can't find this `S.android.intent.extra.TEXT` explanation

What is this S.android.intent why do they use the 'S' character

Comment: `android.intent.extra.TEXT`, `android.intent.extra.SUBJECT`, and `browser_fallback_url` are the names of `Intent` extras. `S.` as a prefix probably means "the value is a string". The values after the `=` and before the `;` represent an encoded form of the `Intent` extra value associated with the name.

Comment: Can I find android.intent.extra.TEXT in AndroidManifest.xml file.

Comment: i want to understand more than android.intent.extra in a schema intent, can you help with a clear syntax.

Comment: android.intent.extra.TEXT You mean "String TEXT = {code ...}"

Comment: "Can I find android.intent.extra.TEXT in AndroidManifest.xml file" -- the names of extras do not appear in manifests.